# GraphQL one to many performance issue and limitation

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I have a DB with 2 tables => Player (10k entries) and Goal (100k entries). I have a relationship *one to many* between them (Player has many Goals)

```js
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
class Player {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [Goal])
  @OneToMany(
    () => Goal,
    goal => goal.player
  )
  goals: Goal[];
  ...
}

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
class Goal {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Player,
    player => player.id
  )
  player: Player;
  ...
}
```

I want to query players and their goals in order to display players rankings in my client app

```
query scorers{
  players{
    id
    totalGoals
  }
}
```

Player resolver looks like this

```
@Resolver(Player)
class PlayerResolver {
  @Query(() => [Player])
  async players() {
    return this.playerRepository.createQueryBuilder("player").getMany();
  }
  @FieldResolver()
  async totalGoals(@Root() player: Player) {
    return this.goalRepository.count({ player });
  }
}
```

This is not performant because it creates a SQL query behind the scene to request the goals for every Player. So it's potentially 10k queries. Is it the best strategy to do this? Also I'm wondering how I could possibly order the players by goals count.
I'm using `type-graphql` and `typeorm`.

Comment: cache totalGoals as a field/prop in player,  shouldn't be counted on [reading] resolver ... update on goal instert

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663128/best-way-to-handle-one-to-many-with-type-graphql-typeorm-and-dataloader

Comment: Querying 10k players at once seems to be the actual problem imo.

Comment: @xadm is it something common to create cache field/prop in SQL database? Do you references about that?

Comment: it's frequently used and costly ... how do you sort players by totalGoals ... in a season? complexity grows exponentialy

Comment: @xadm I sort player by totalgoals in a season! Also I have to sort players by minutes played, yellow/red cards and other individual stats. Having cache field/prop for each of stat seems to be the most performant solution from a user point of view. When I run my query threw my joins it can take until 10 seconds to respond :-/

Comment: ...and don't you think that you should have this data [stats] at least precalculated [in separate table] ... any DB design knowledge? DB [materialized] views ?

Comment: I have limited DB knowledge. I designed relationships between my tables but no views nor materialized views. I'm gonna explore this topic. Thank you @xadm

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to build the query with join ahead of time (on query resolver level, using `@Info` to read requested fields) or use a DataLoader library to batch the queries and solve the N + 1 problem.